# Why i can connect to every https website using http

Tags: networking, website, https

Facebook is a https website (https://facebook.com) and when i enter http://facebook.com it connect without any problem is this the case with every https website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the case with every HTTPS website?

No.

HTTP (typically port 80) and HTTPS (typically port 443) are two totally separate services that often appear to work together.

More and more often, when you navigate to `http://example.com`, you'll be connecting with a server whose *sole responsibility* is to redirect you to `https://example.com`.

Typically, if you supply a path, query string etc... then you'll be redirected with these maintained.

For example, navigating to `http://facebook.com/abcdefg` will simply forward you on to `https://facebook.com/abcdefg`, with no regard to whether or not that page actually exists (it doesn't currently - you'll ultimately get a [404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404))

```
$ curl -v http://facebook.com/abcdefg
*   Trying 157.240.221.35...
* Connected to facebook.com (157.240.221.35) port 80 (#0)
> GET /abcdefg HTTP/1.1
> Host: facebook.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Location: https://facebook.com/abcdefg
< Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
< X-FB-Debug: 2G7V3yvcTiKIEIYOnCwTSvQD5L6EMm615YxBaz//l1OagX1sknJlyy6Ogl6bHLtm8xyh9oC+C7+I0N3FpTv94g==
< Date: Wed, 13 May 2020 12:04:05 GMT
< Alt-Svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=3600
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host facebook.com left intact
```

In the case of facebook, there is actually a second redirect that forwards you to `https://www.facebook.com/abcdefg` (adding the `www.` prefix).

---

There are also other technologies that help to secure the web, such as [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) which instructs a browser to *always* use HTTPS when contacting a particular site... even if the user attempts to use HTTP.

HSTS is also extended by the use of a "*preload list*" that includes many of the the top domains and is shipped with browsers. This means that even if you've never visited a site before, you may find that the browser doesn't even attempt to use HTTP.

---

Historically, back when HTTPS was new and still expensive (both from a "*certificates cost money*" and processing point of view), people more commonly offered both HTTP and HTTPS access to the same site, allowing the user to "*decide*" whether they wanted the encryption and authentication.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the website.  What you are seeing is that http://facebook.. is converted by the website to https://facebook...  So it is not a matter that http:// is pervasive at all, it just means the transition to https:// is ongoing. The great majority (but not 100%) of the sites I visit at https://  . But the sites convert your http:// so as to allow you in.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the web site, if the web site owner needs to allow the users without HTTPS (default port 443) client support to connect, they also tend to run a HTTP server (default port 80) as well.